# how to exponentiate a number in Long format in Kotlin?

Tags: math, kotlin, long-integer, pow, computation

`var count = 20L`
I need to raise the number to a power, but how to do it?

`this.pow()` does not accept Long

Comment: What kind of power? An integer?

Comment: You may refer this link `https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/pow.html`

Answer (score -1):

Since kotlin-stdlib provides only `Double.pow(x: Double)`, `Double.pow(n: Int)`, `Float.pow(x: Float)` and `Float.pow(n: Int)`, I assume that you are trying to use one of these functions. So `this` is either `Double` or `Float`. Since both of them are already approximate, you can use approximate exponent as well:

```
double.pow(long.toDouble())
float.pow(long.toFloat())
```

Comment: double can represent exactly any integer between -2\**52 and 2\**52.